# How full is my innodb shared table space?

Tags: mysql, innodb, maintenance, monitoring

How can I find out how much data is in the innodb shared table space.

I have a massive shared idb file but I suspect that it contains only about 350 Gigs of data. I need to know how full it is so I can prevent it from expanding as I have very little disk space left. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's in `ibdata1`?  How much free space do you currently have?  What is the output of

```
 SHOW TABLE STATUS;
```

And

```
 SHOW CREATE TABLE  -- for the largest table
```

Is this 'your' machine?  Or a Cloud server?  Do you have access to another machine with a big disk?

Knowing how "full it is" won't necessarily help you avoid running out of disk space.

With answers to the above questions, we *may* be able to plot a path that does not end in disaster.

Comment: Yes, ibdata1  
  
-rw-r----- 1 mysql mysql 935G Jan 17 09:55 ibdata1  

It is my machine. I have other servers, I'm setting up a new master. I just want to know how to monitor the percentage of that ibdata1 file that is filled up so that I can know more or less how much data to archive. I realise that I can still run out of space but, as long as this ibdata1 file doesn't grow I should be ok till I have an alternative.   

Show table status and show create table have a lot of private data. What are you looking for?

Comment: Sorry if you have been spammed here. I've been trying to get the formatting right.

Comment: The `Data_free` in `SHOW TABLE STATUS` will give you the free space in `ibdata1` (since you don't have file_per_table).

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can use information_schema.tables to get the table size:

```
select sum( data_length + index_length ) from information_schema.tables;
```

BTW, you should backup your data and the separate tablespace(By setting innodb_file_per_table=1) is a easier way to manage, backup, discovery and transferring.

Comment: data_length is just the size of the primary key (it says so in the manual). You can't rely on this.

Comment: Thank you for pointing it out. I mean ( data_length + index_length ), not just data_length.

Comment: I know, but that doesn't change anything. You can't rely on it. You're missing all other columns.

Comment: I'll be using innodb_file_per_table=1 on my next server. It's impossible to make that change to this server because that big innodb1 file can't shrink.

Comment: @tombom The clustered index contains all the columns data. The clustered index is a B+ tree sorted by the primary key, and all the row data is stored in the leaf pages.

Comment: Hm, maybe you're right. Still those values are just estimates. I tried monitoring database growth once with this, the values are incredibly wrong, even if you do a `analzye table`.